# Unable to install some applications on windows 7 64 bit (These files can't be opened error)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I get the following error when I try to install some application on my windows 7 64 bit system.

[image]

How do I turn this off as I know that the applications that I'm installing are trusted.

I have turned off windows defender and tried to tweak internet explorer security settings according to the first few google results but yet I have the same error. (I also created a new user account and tried importing new registry keys but nothing even then)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try,

Reset IE, open IE and go to the Advanced tab and hit the reset button.

Use Microsoft System Restore, pick a date before this problem started.

Comment: will uninstalling IE solve this issue? I don't even use that browser really

Comment: You cannot uninstall it, did you do as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/17baf19c-cdd5-4a21-9daa-67e6abb9d566):

> 1. Create another user (admin)
> 2. Switch to the newly-created user
> 3. Run regedit
> 4. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
> 5. Right-click -> export to a public folder or root dir
> 6. Switch back to your original account
> 7. Remove the the above keys
> 8. Run the exported .reg

Comment: I have tried these solutions but they don't work.